# How to use @Html.Action as a part of view in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, razor, view, partial, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having a problem like this:

I have 2 files cshtml, 
Index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  ....
  @Html.Action("Contact", "Post")
  ....
</body>
</html>
```

Contact.cshtml

```
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Post", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="right_contact col-sm-3">
                <h3>Regist</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TEN_DANG_KY, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "adviceName", @placeholder = "Họ và tên" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TEN_DANG_KY, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default smAdvice" id="adviceSubmit" value="Đăng Ký">
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

And this my controller:

```
public ActionResult Contact([Bind(Include = "MA_THONG_TIN,TEN_DANG_KY,EMAIL,SDT")] LIEN_HE lh)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.THEM_LIEN_HE(lh.TEN_DANG_KY, lh.EMAIL, lh.SDT);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Msg = "Chúng tôi sẽ liên hệ cho bạn sớm nhất có thể.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

When ModelState.IsValid == false, it return View() (Contact.cshtml) but i want to return (Index.cshtml) with the error messages have been caught at ModelState.IsValid.

Hope the helping!

Comment: Use `return View("Index");` in order to return to specific view. You are trying to redirect to action which is not correct.

Comment: I want send **ViewBag.Msg** to View(), how to do it?

Comment: You can access `ViewBag.Msg` in returned View.

Comment: if return View() it will return Contact.cshtml but i want to return Index.html with ViewBag.Msg.

Comment: While returning view, mention the "view name" to which you want to return. If you wont specify any view name, it will return to default view. In your case, default view is "contact.cshtml"

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.